# error: property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Tags: ios, view, lldb

I'm debugging my code and trying to figure out the size of the view using this:

```
p view.frame.size.height
```

but I'm getting this error:

error: property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UIView *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

any of you knows why or how can I debug the size of my view?

Comment: I think you cannot use dot notation like that in the console, can you try this, i think it's going to work : `[[[[self view] frame] size] height]`

Comment: I think you can use NSLog instead -- NSLog(@"Frame Height: %f", view.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 89):

If you hate typecasting every time, you can try this:

```
(lldb) expr @import UIKit
(lldb) po self.view.bounds
```

Since Xcode 7.2 is now available, I think we should update the answer.
I find the answer here, [Why can't LLDB print view.bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885255/why-cant-lldb-print-view-bounds)

Answer (score 53):

Try this

```
p (CGRect)[view frame]
```

Alternative to get the frame of the view:

```
po view
```

Comment: I get this error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x65).
The process has been returned to the state before execution.

Comment: I got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS because I was calling frame on the wrong object. Instead of: p (CGRect)[myviewcontroller frame] should be p (CGRect)[[myviewcontroller view] frame]

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
po view.layer.frame.size.height
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Makes me think that `view.frame` is simply be a shortcut for `view.layer.frame` that LLDB doesn't have access to...

Answer (score 3):

it should have outer bracket in the first answer,like this:

```
p ((CGRect)[cell frame])
```

output:

```
(CGRect) $5 = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=44)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a pch file , add these lines of code to the file:

```
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif  

#endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */
```

Next, link the pch file to your project:

[image]

Run the app again, then you should be able to use the dot notation in lldb console:

```
(lldb) po self.view.bounds
```

For how to add a pch file , see the answer here [PCH File in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126037/4975761)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot use dot notation in the console, try to use get method.

Comment: this worked in my case, trying to get [self traitCollection]; Dot notation failed with error, "property 'traitCollection' not found on object of type 'UIView *'", but using [self traitCollection] worked!

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem and i solved it. Your class might be inherited from "UIViewController". It must be inherited from "UIView" so as to make an frame object in it.